# cxGrid immediate row selection

Tags: delphi, devexpress

What settings must I apply to a cxGrid so I can have an immediate row selection when I click inside the grid ?

I want to select a desired row immediately.

Right now I must first click the grid and then select the row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  GridView.Control.SetFocus;
  // just in case if DataSet is UniDirectional:
  if GridView.DataController.FocusedRowIndex < 0 then
    GridView.DataController.FocusedRowIndex := 0;
```

Comment: cxGrid1DBTableView1.DataController.FocusedRowIndex := -1;   <0 wont compile

Comment: @user763539 - sorry, my mistake, there must be `if GridView.DataController.FocusedRowIndex < 0 then ...` I corrected the answer, now is ok :)